# Bizarre Answer looks like Off-Topic

Tags: discussion, flagging, specific-answer, deleting-posts

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111211/in-what-era-or-tech-level-in-earths-history-did-people-have-the-ability-to-cros) is about navigation on a super sized sea on a super-earth.

It received a bizarre <s>"religious"</s> [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/111531/28789).

I don't feel like this answer is adding anything to the discussion and worse I guess it's blatantly off-topic.

Is my guess correct? Can we flag it for deletion?

Comment: I changed the tags a bit, as "on-topic" and "off-topic" are more often used for questions. You wouldn't tag answers, as tags are for categorizing questions, but you can flag them for example as "not an answer". I'll take a look and maybe write an answer here.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I'm not against religious views it happens the answer looks off-topic. Replace "GODS" with "ADVANCED ALIEN CIVILIZATION" for example and the post keeps bizarre and off-topic. If the question don't have a [reality-check] tag so it's fine to me.

Comment: Just to add a bit: [reality-check] just means in-universe-reality. If someone posts a magic-world-with-aliens question and asks for in-universe consistency of their magic system it would be totally fine to use the reality-check tag (there have been quite a lot of discussions about this, but that's how it's commonly used). But in this specific case the querent asks about real-world history and real-world science and therefore an alien/magic/god-technology/... answer is simply "not an answer".

Comment: @Raditz_35 I was in doubt if I can tag that question off-topic and I cannot find a way to rephrase it. Pls suggest a better way and I gladly will edit my question

Comment: Update: the answer has been deleted. (It can of course be undeleted if other folks feel that it is a valid answer that was mistakenly deleted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily call it a "religious" answer, but it certainly doesn't answer the question. It seems to be intended to be some kind of answer like "the last big civilization left technology on the planet and now we view this magnificent technology as something given to us by the gods".

It doesn't address in any way which past era in our real world would be able to cross this distance with their ships - I certainly don't believe that the "age of the God's" is an era that we should account for in our real-world Earth's history. It might be fine in a fantasy setting where you are willing to use such tropes, but the querent seems to be searching for an answer based in real-world history and science.

I left a comment and flagged it as "Not an answer".

That is the general process when encountering something in an answer post that doesn't seem to address the question or falls short of being a real answer, for example if someone mentions that they don't have the reputation to comment and therefore misused the answer box. We'll see what the community thinks about the answer and maybe the user who answered will edit their post to clarify what they mean. There is always the possibility of simply misunderstanding one another.

---

This has nothing to do with whether this is about religious believes or not. The answer doesn't really address the question in any meaningful way and therefore it's "Not an answer" and should be flagged as such. I also don't think we should make any sweeping statements about banning religion from non-religion questions. If your religious believes help you write a meaningful answer or add something that could be used to grant the qeurent's in-universe logic some kind of plausibility then by all means: add your religious views to your answer. Just don't expect anyone to free you of the requirement to support your claims, especially if someone asks about history or science.

If you encounter religious views and don't like them because you feel that they are unsupported claims you can simply downvote them to show your disagreement with the statements and possibly write a comment about how you are having doubts about the validity of the claims presented in the answer. You shouldn't get into any religious flame wars, though.

Upvote what you think is good, downvote what you think is not good, flag what you think doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did some spot checking and it looks like about 1/3 of the answers don't answer the question.  Rather, they're (often lengthy) comments.  People were having a tough time taking the OP at his/her word about that ocean and weren't focusing on the issue of the relevant technology level.

Please note, however, that we're a bit <s>lazy</s>lenient when it comes to holding people to the relevance of their answers.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Physics.SE, etc., this is a highly creative site focused as much on unreality as reality.  For example, it's very common to see the "You can't do that, but you could do this" type of answer.  Regrettably, it's also true that you will often see answers that reflect the fact that the answerer didn't read the question very well.  Indeed, that's a hallmark of people who swoop in via the Stack Exchange app, drop a rushed answer because it's all the time they had while riding the bus to work, and swoop away (never to be seen again).

But, in the end, what one person judges to be an answer of little value another often finds to be a gem of inspiration.  And so we don't often sweat the little things.

Comment: What makes you think that these answers are from people that are visiting via the App as opposed to people that are visiting the website? It's not like there are any "Sent via RandomPhone" texts under each answer.

Comment: @Secespitus, I freely admit that I'm taking the limited evidence of a few who have admitted they came in via the app and the consistency their answers share (short, not on point, often unregistered, always a first post and never contributing again) and jumping to the potentially unworthy and not well substantiated belief that nearly all such answers are thanks to the app.  As with all things like this, I'm free to have my opinion and you're free to prove me wrong.

Comment: If anecdotal evidence is enough than it should suffice for example if I say that I am often using the App and I have seen mods mention in the chat that they are sometimes on mobile. Otherwise you are also free to provide evidence for your claim that the App is at fault making Appusers bad and non-Appusers good. Without any evidence there is no reason to do anything against the App and it's quite not-nice to demonize (strong word, but I can't find a more fitting one) all Appusers.